# Filtro de Objetos hierárquicos

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, design-pattern, reflexão

Tenho uma tela Asp.net MVC 4.5 C# razor tipada por uma classe principal:

```
public class ClassePaiDTO 
{
    public virtual ICollection<Filho1DTO> Filho1s { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Filho2DTO> Filho2s { get; set; }

    //codigo Filter imaginado
    private FilterSelected()
    {
       this.Filho1s =  this.Filho1s.Where(s => s.Selected).ToList();
       this.Filho2s =  this.Filho2s.Where(s => s.Selected).ToList();
    }
}

public class Filho1DTO 
{
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Neto1DTO> Neto1s { get; set; }
}

public class Filho2DTO
{
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}

public class Neto1DTO 
{
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

Após executar um POST, no meu controller, gostaria de executar um filter para pegar somente o que estão marcados como true. Ex:

```
objClassePaiDTO.FilterSelected();
```

Depois disso, apenas utilizaria um AutoMapper para transformar em Entidade. Tentei utilizar um resolver pra efetuar um filtro, mas nao é sempre que preciso disso, ou seja, somente no post mesmo da minha tela.

Como o sistema é repleto de "classes Pais". Qual a implementação limpa e semântica necessária para esta situação?

A princípio tinha pensado em criar uma classe abstrata:

- Com uma propriedade bool chamada Selected;
- Com um metodo abstrato chamado Filter();
- Toda classe que precisasse filtrar eu herdaria desta classe.

Mas acho que me compliquei no design e não consegui chegar num denominador comum.

Depois pensei em criar um reflection para:

Quando a classe pai chamar o metodo FilterSelected() ele iria navegar pelas propriedade checando sem tem listas de filhos, netos e afins filtrando tudo que encontrasse pela frente.

Confesso que essa ultima abordagem achei meio extrema, mas caso der certo, iria funcionar de forma genérica para outras classes Pai do sistema.

Comment: Teria como colocar o código do FilterSelected()

Comment: Na verdade ele ainda não existe, adicionei na classe pai o imaginado. Gostaria que ele fosse em cascata.

Comment: Se eu entendi bem, você quer que cada lista de filhos e ou netos sejam filtrados quando o selected for true? Se for isso, eu criaria uma interface em comum, e faria um extension method para aquele tipo de interface que ordenaria quando fosse true, então sempre que você quiser ele ordenado é so chamar este metodo. Da para fazer com classe abstrata tb. Agora se você na verdade quer uma lista única com todos os itens Selecionados, entao da pra fazer com método recursivo.

Comment: Seria um objetoPai que quando eu chamasse filterSelected, ele sairia filtrando todas a listas e sublistas abaixo, deixando ele limpo.

Answer (score 1):

Eu criaria uma classe abstrata como esta abaixo onde Pai,Filhos e netos herdariam:

```
public abstract class SortBase : ISortBase
{
    #region ISortBase Members

    public IList<ISortBase> ChildList { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }

    public virtual void Sort()
    {
        ChildList = ChildList.Where(x => x.Selected).ToList();
        foreach (var sortBase in ChildList)
            sortBase.Sort();

    }

    #endregion
}
```

Agora se sua classe pai/filho e etc tem mais de uma lista de filhos que precisa ser ordenada também, eu usaria reflection para chamar o método Sort dessas coleções de "SortBase".

Comment: Legal, mas existem situações que filhos e netos teriam mais de uma lista que precisaria ser filtradas mesmo, acho que vou recorrer ao Reflection.

Comment: Agora que vi, A nomenclatura do meu código acima deveria ser Filter e não Sort, mas o código é o mesmo. Acredito que você terá que usar reflection mesmo.